# RequestTimeTooSkewed: boto3 upload sometimes fails when run in thread

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I often want to upload files to Amazon S3 in the background. I'm using threads for this.
Sometimes, but not always, this results in a RequestTimeTooSkewed error.

```
import threading
from pathlib import Path
import boto3

def upload_file_s3(
    local_path: Path,
    s3_path: Path,
    bucket: str,
) -> None:
    ACCESS_KEY = ""
    SECRET_KEY = ""
    client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        region_name="eu-central-1",
        use_ssl=False,
        verify=False,
    )
    client.upload_file(str(local_path), bucket, str(s3_path))


local_path = Path('/tmp/testfile')
s3_path = Path('testfile')
bucket = 'my_bucket'

thread = threading.Thread(target=upload_file_s3, args=(local_path, s3_path, bucket))
thread.start()
```

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the UploadPart operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error **RequestTimeTooSkewed** occurs when the difference between your system’s time and the Amazon S3 server's time is too large.

This is verified prior to any S3 upload. The reason this is verified is to prevent [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) of your command.

You can sync your clock using [ntpdate](https://www.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.8-series/ntpdate/) which polls NTP ([Network time protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)) servers, such as the American [NIST](https://time.nist.gov/) (National Institute of Standards and Technology).

To do that, perform these steps:

```
1) install [ntpdate][1] (If not already installed)
sudo apt install ntpdate

2) Sync time against some NTP server (e.g. NIST's)
sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov
```

Since these commands are both performed using sudo, you'll need to enter your credentials on the first one.